# Changing from a datagridview to a simple textbox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, textbox, oledb

I have a program that puts a cell of data from an excel file and writes it to a datagridview cell. However since I'm only trying to write one cell of data I'm thinking it might be a better Idea to write the data from the excel file to a simple textbox.

I'm having trouble finding out how to interface a simple textbox with an excel file. If anyone has some suggestions on how I might accomplish this I would greatly appreciate it.

Below is my current code for working with my datagridview.

```
'This code sample here uses a for next loop to match the excel column and rows up with the datagridview's rows and columns. 
Dim rowindex As Integer
Dim columnindex As Integer
For rowindex = 1 To DataGridView3.RowCount
    For columnindex = 1 To DataGridView3.ColumnCount
        objworksheet3.Cells(rowindex + 3, columnindex + 1) =     DataGridView3(columnindex - 1, rowindex - 1).Value
    Next
Next

'This code uses the oledatadapter to pull only the cells that I want from the excel file to populate the datagridview cell. 
MyCommand3 = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [myWorksheet$B3:B4]", MyConnection)

ds3 = New System.Data.DataSet()
MyCommand3.Fill(ds3)
```

Answer (score 1):

> For rowindex = 1 To DataGridView3.RowCount

I suggest, For rowindex = 0 To DataGridView3.RowCount -1

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now how would I implement this for-next loop for a simple textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can get data directly from your dataset; for example to retrieve data from the first row of the first column:

```
Textbox1.text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0).ToString
```

if you want to fetch more cells you can cycle through rows and columns

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help! Any idea how I might fashion the for-next loop for a textbox? I'm not able to use columncount or rowcount for a textbox.

Comment: Why would you iterate on textboxes? In your question you said that you had to write a single textbox or am I missing something? How many textboxes do you have in your form?

Comment: This works great but it still doesn't save changes to the excel file.